# Is it possible to reassign an approval that belongs to someone else?

Tags: flow

I have set up a series of flows which include approval blocks, and a question has been raised what happens should an approver not be available.

I can see the possibility to create a second approval to a different person after x time, but this at minimum builds in a delay, and at least where I work that second person is not well defined so is likely to be different every time.

Is there a way for an admin to find an approval assigned to someone else, and manually reassign it? I know I can reassign approvals meant for myself, so the functionality is present, but either the permission is not available, or I can't work it out.

The only option I can think of at the moment is to have the admin (myself currently) as an additional approver on every approval block, and then I can just reassign my own version of an approval request to whoever I wish, but I am uncomfortable with that because it effectively means I can approve things well above my station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been stuck on this one this week as well. I had an approver who fell sick for a long period of time, so the flow could not be completed.

In this case approvals can be seen as e-mails. You can't really open an email from somebody else unless you gained access to that person's account. Which makes a lot of sense because otherwise approvals would lose there validity. And you can't approve 'as an impersonator'.

These are the options I found out you can work with:

- Use a parallel time-out on your approval redirecting the approval to somebody else.
- Cancel the current running flow and restart from 0 without the approver blocking it. (I ended up using this solution.)
- Use the entity 'Approval' (msdyn_flow_approval) to manually approve or reject the entire(!) approval. (This setting can be found in Flow > Data > Entities > View All)

One thing is certain when you look around on the internet: "You can't alter a running flow."

Comment: Most of this parallels what I already thought, but your 3rd option is new to me so I am looking into that, thank you very much.

Comment: Guess these are still the only options?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option which I am using:

When creating an approval, add a service account along with the original approver. Select the option of wait for any response.

This will send the same approval to original approver and the service account.
Now when an approval is stuck, login to the service account and re assign it to the new approver.

Comment: 3 years on and I can't believe this is still the only option.